# Numerical errors in specifying covariance of two (or more) random signals

Tags: statistics, variance, signal-processing, covariance

I am looking at conditioning randomly generated signals that produce very precise first and second order statistics.

Lets consider two randomly generated, 1-D signals $[X,Y]$ of arbitrary, but finite length. And we condition these signals to have zero mean and unit variance.

Lets begin with 100 elements, generated with some python code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10101)

slen = 100 #signal length

#each column of x is a signal, X = x[:,0], Y = x[:,1]
x = np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(slen,2))

#Zero mean
x = x-np.mean(x, axis=0)
#Unit variance
x = x/np.sqrt(np.mean(x**2,axis=0))
```

With zero mean and unit variance, we can create a covariance matrix $R_{ij}$ that specifies our desired variance and covariance between our two signals. Following a standard Cholesky decomposition to pre-multiply our signals by in order to give them the desired second order statistics. Just use some arbitrary values here.

$R_{ij}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.25 \\
0.25 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

$L_{ij}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0.25 & 0.96824584 
\end{bmatrix}$

```
Rij = np.array([[1,0.25],[0.25,1]])
Lij = np.linalg.cholesky(Rij)
```

We can now pre-multiply our signals by $L_{ij}$ and should return two signals with the given stats in $R_{ij}$.

$\begin{bmatrix}
x'\\
y'
\end{bmatrix} = L_{ij}
\begin{bmatrix}
x^{T}\\
y^{T}
\end{bmatrix}$

```
xp = np.matmul(Lij, x.T).T
```

If we check the stats of the actual signal, we (not surprisingly) get something close-ish.

```
print('Signal stats')
print('R_xx = ', np.mean(xp[:,0]**2))
print('R_xy = ', np.mean(xp[:,0]*xp[:,1]))
print('R_yy = ', np.mean(xp[:,1**2]))
```

Resulting in

```
Signal stats
R_xx =  0.9999999999999996
R_xy =  0.19102763783107032
R_yy =  0.9705138189155358
```

Obviously $R_{xx}$ is dead on, and $R_{xy}$ and $R_{yy}$ are clearly in the ballpark, but not as accurate as most would like. (It turns out that it is ALWAYS $R_{yy}$ that is less accurate than $R_{xx}$, more on that later).

I am fairly sure this stems from the fact that our 'randomly' generated signal of just 100 elements is not statistically converged. I.e. the conditioned $X$ and $Y$ vectors do not have zero covariance as required by this Cholesky decomp technique to work. Indeed we can check this:

```
print('Random vector stats')
print('R_xy = ', np.mean(x[:,0]*x[:,1]))
```

yields

```
Random vector stats
R_xy =  -0.06090639375114042
```

We can improve these results by increasing the length of the originally random signals, so say, 10,000 elements, and the results do improve:

```
Signal stats
R_xx =  1.000000000000001
R_xy =  0.2632783322133913
R_yy =  1.0066391661066976
```

And the error will scale with the non-zero covariance error.

This leads to my first question:

`Can I condition the original signals X and Y to truly have zero covariance and give a better level of accuracy in this procedure?`

My second question comes from practical observation involving the exact same procedure with variable $R_{ij}$ values.

Swapping in a smaller $R_{xy}$ value to something like

$R_{ij}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.001 \\
0.001 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

We get the following results

```
Signal stats
R_xx =  0.9999999999999996
R_xy =  -0.059906363297935916
R_yy =  0.9998781872734045
```

So the accuracy of the procedure also depends on the level of covariance we attemp to set.

Playing around with values of $R_{xy}$ yields:

```
Smaller $R_{xy}$ yields more accurate $R_{yy}$
```

So my second question is:

```
What is the source of this pattern and can it be improved? (Preconditioning?)
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best link to "de-correlating" or "whitening" the signals I have found

https://courses.media.mit.edu/2010fall/mas622j/whiten.pdf